# Work done in equilibrium positions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, work

I am confused in work done against friction. Let $F$ be the friction when a  big stone is pushed by person on ground and $T$ be the component of force applied by a  person in the direction of displacement $S$.

I think $T$ should be greater than $F$, otherwise stone will not move. Then $T$ is not equal to $F$. But why do we check work done against friction as $FS$? I mean why isn't it $TS$?

Comment: Friction applies force $F$ and you have to overcome it ... All the way during your travel at a distance $s$ , friction is active ... And work done by friction is $Fs$ ... But total work is $Ts -Fs$ ...

Comment: Please sir give the name of any good book or web site to clear this concept

Comment: Look into **University Physics by Young** , **Mechanics by Kleppner** , lectures of Walter lewin ..

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ > $F$  , the stone will have an acceleration ,say $a$ .

$$M_{stone}a=T-F$$

So , $a=\frac{T-F}{M_{stone}} >0$ .

The stone will have the speed $v(t)=at$ , so a kinetic energy $E_k=\frac{M_{stone}v^2}{2}=\frac{M_{stone}(at)^2}{2}=\frac{t^2(T-F)^2}{2M_{stone}}$ .

The idea is that you have done the work $TS$ , which goes in overcoming friction ( $FS$ ) and accelerating the stone ( $E_k$) .

As an exercise  , try to write the equation $TS=FS+E_k$ and see if it's checked.